# Could WinRM allow local logon but disallow remote logon?

Tags: windows, powershell, winrm

I am trying to setup a windows server, the WinRM service to allow access for a user only locally via invoke-command, but disallow access remotely...

I have tried editing the permissions with:

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.PowerShell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI
```

But this didn't help me really, I have also tried varies other ways, looked into this for a day but I cannot seem to find a way to make this to work.

So my question is, is there a way to allow a domain user to do Invoke-Command locally only, but disallow access to WinRM remotely ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is [`AccessMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-pssessionconfiguration?view=powershell-7#parameters).

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.PowerShell -AccessMode Local
```

The options are `Disabled`, `Local`, `Remote`.

Comment: This did help, but is it possible to configure only 1 user to have the -AccessMode Local, instead of the entire configuration to allow only local access ?